# Как кэшировать и сохранить картинку?

Tags: objective-c

Есть массив pictures из 20 url адресов;

**И есть метод который скачивает картинки:**

```
(void)start:(UIImageView *)displayImage: (UILabel *)nameImage: (UIButton *)startDownload {

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURL *data = [NSURL URLWithString:[_pictures objectAtIndex:startDownload.tag]];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *download = [session downloadTaskWithURL:data];

    NSLog(@"Download complete for %ld cell", startDownload.tag);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [nameImage setText:[[_pictures objectAtIndex:startDownload.tag] lastPathComponent]];
        [displayImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:data]]];

    }); [download resume];

}
```

Comment: Вы могли просто отредактировать существующий вопрос, а не удалять и создавать по новой. Ну, теперь вы это знаете. А код проще всего отформатировать следующим образом: вставить в текст вопроса "как есть", выделить и нажать `Ctrl`+`K`.

Comment: на гите найти готовую библиотеку. например: https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke

Comment: А как сделать это через NSFileManager?
Я новичок и никогда с этим не сталкивался.

Comment: практически любая библиотека (включая приведнную мной выше) будет это делать через NSFileManager

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать.)

Comment: Решил это создав путь в которий записывал скачанную картинку.